# 3 MongoDB Collections, 3 AJAX Requests: How to simplify into 1 request?

Tags: ajax, mongodb

I have 3 MongoDB collections and each of them are defined something like:

```
@app.route('/getMyData', methods=['GET'])
def getMyData():
    myDataCollection = db["data_1"]
    data = list(myDataCollection.find({},{"Name":1,"Website":1,"Twitter":1,"Description":1,"_id":0}))
    return jsonify(data=data)
```

Then I retrieve these data using AJAX requests (one for each collection so 3 requests) as follows:

```
function getDataFromDB() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/getMyData',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
             // code goes here
        }
    });
}
```

How can I simplify this? It seems like I cannot query multiple collections in MongoDB.

Comment: Approaches vary depending on language and general framework as to what to do here. One approach is to have a kind of general handler that accepts something like a "batch" request, then processes various instructions sent in that request and returning the "batch result" of each instruction in the response. For a simple endpoint where you just need to combine output of multiple queries, then do exactly that and effectively "concatenate" the result response into a single response. Not entirely clear which of these is your actual intent without further explaination.

Comment: Ok. How do I receive a batch result from querying multiple collections in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is designed so that each operation/query deals with one collection.

[MongoDB CRUD Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/crud-introduction/)

The design of your DB should take this into consideration. So if you need lists of each collection you'll have to have one for each.

As Blakes Seven mentioned, what you could do is set up some server side script that makes the three calls, then organises the response 'data' so that you only have one call in your application. You're still having to make three DB calls though; just depends on your application/DB/server design.